# Scatter with 2 y-axes and datetick

Tags: matlab, scatter

I would really appreciate some help.

I have to independent datasets. Each dataset contains two variables: dates (as datenumber) and corresponding data.  I need to plot both datasets on one scatter plot with dates on x-axis and  two y-axes. I have been trying with the following code:

```
figure(1); 
scatter(x1,y1,'g'); 
set(gca); 
ax1=gca;
set(ax1,'YColor','g'); 
ax2 = axes('Position',get(gca,'Position'),'YAxisLocation','right', XTick'[],'Color','none','YColor','r'); 
hold on; scatter(x2,y2,'r');
```

Now, this gives correct y-axis on the right side, however on the right side I end up with two overlapping y-axes. 
Also, I need to change x-axis  so that it displays dates as opposed to datenumbers. I've tried to incorporate datetick into the code but it again gives me two overlapping x-axes.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

thank you

Comment: can you provide sample data so we can reproduce the problem in a working example? Thanks!

Comment: My sample data:
x1 (date)
732490   
732509    
732512   
732513  
732521  
732528

y1   
7.828 
7.609 
22.422  
14.758  
26.258  
1.477

x2 (date) 
732402 
732403 
732404 
732404 
732433

y2
0.693 
0.645 
0.668 
0.669 
0.668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your script with your sample input and found no problems. Anyway, here's a solution which uses the matlab function `plotyy`, which is suited to simple plots like this:

```
%generate input
x1=[732490 732509 732512 732513 732521 732528];
y1=[7.828 7.609 22.422 14.758 26.258 1.477];
x2=[732402 732403 732404 732404 732433];
y2=[0.693 0.645 0.668 0.669 0.668];

figure(1); 
[ax, h1,h2]=plotyy(x1,y1,x2,y2,'scatter');

%set colors manually
green=[0 1 0];
red=[1 0 0];
set(h1,'cdata',green);
set(h2,'cdata',red);
set(ax(1),'ycolor',green);
set(ax(2),'ycolor',red);

%note the 'keepticks' and 'keeplimits' options
datetick(ax(1),'x','yyyy-mm-dd','keepticks','keeplimits');
datetick(ax(2),'x','yyyy-mm-dd','keepticks','keeplimits');
```

[image]

Without the `datetick` call the `plotyy` function synchronizes the `xtick`s in the plot. When you call `datetick`, it recalculates the ticks, unless you explicitly tell it not to, see the option `keepticks`, and this is seen as two sets of `x` axes (even though the `x` coordinates are the same, the ticks are located at different positions). The `keeplimits` option is needed to preserve the original `xlim`. It obviously needs some more manual work to get plots like this sufficiently pretty.

Also note that I set the axes and data colors manually: there might be a way to do this more elegantly.

**Update**: `keeplimits` originally missing

**Update2**: changed sample data to correspond to updated question comment

Comment: thank you! I had to edit it a bit, removing 'keepticks' as it was shifting data and having no 'XTick'  for ax(2). but it worked. thanks again.