# plotting using separate axes on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm looking to create a plot of two time series in matlab with separate axes because they are of completely different size. I understand that plotyy function is the function to use however I am having difficulty with the dates. Currently the dates are in date-vector format, so there are three separate columns containing the year, the month and the date. Do I need to convert the dates, and if so then how? Thanks in advance

Comment: Indeed, you should probably convert your date vector to a datenum, then you can use that for plotting. See maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663723/scatter-with-2-y-axes-and-datetick), similar stuff.

Comment: You'd be more likely to get an answer if you paste reproducible code here!